# Ruby On Rails, params lost after redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, post, submit

I have a page where the user pays fees, and on submit gets redirected to the same page showing the payment done. I'm passing the id on  redirect, but it is lost which is causing an error.

Here is the controller action:

```
def pay_all_fees 

    @target_action='pay_all_fees'
    @target_controller='parent_wise_fee_payments'
        if params[:id].present?
      id = params[:id]
      else id = 4

       end

      @students=Student.find_all_by_sibling_id(Guardian.find(id).ward_id)
      @guardian = Guardian.find(id)
      @students.each do |student|
            fetch_all_fees

      end

      if request.post?
      status=true
      MultiFeesTransaction.transaction do
        multi_fees_transaction= MultiFeesTransaction.create(params[:multi_fees_transaction])
        begin
          finance_transactions=FinanceTransaction.create!(params[:transactions].values)
        rescue Exception => e
          status=false
        end

        if status and (multi_fees_transaction.valid? && finance_transactions.all?(&:valid?))
          multi_fees_transaction.finance_transactions=finance_transactions
          flash[:notice]="#{t('fees_paid')}"
        else
          flash[:notice]="#{t('fee_payment_failed')}"
          raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
        end
      end
      redirect_to :controller => 'parent_wise_fee_payments', :action => 'pay_all_fees', :id=>id
    end
      get_paid_fees
   end
```

And this is the error in the production log:

```
Processing ParentWiseFeePaymentsController#pay_all_fees (for 178.135.80.106 at 2015-08-03 13:11:29) [POST]
  Parameters: {"multi_fees_transaction"=>{"student_id"=>"4", "payment_mode"=>"Cash", "payment_note"=>"", "amount"=>"500.00", "transaction_date"=>"2015-08-03"}, "controller"=>"parent_wise_fee_payments", "transactions"=>{"4"=>{"payee_type"=>"Student", "title"=>"Receipt No.. (Multiple Fees) F3", "payment_mode"=>"Cash", "finance_id"=>"3", "category_id"=>"14", "payment_note"=>"", "payee_id"=>"4", "amount"=>"", "finance_type"=>"FinanceFee", "transaction_date"=>"2015-08-03"}, "2"=>{"payee_type"=>"Student", "title"=>"Receipt No.. (Multiple Fees) F3", "payment_mode"=>"Cash", "finance_id"=>"3", "category_id"=>"14", "payment_note"=>"", "payee_id"=>"1", "amount"=>"500", "finance_type"=>"FinanceFee", "transaction_date"=>"2015-08-03"}}, "action"=>"pay_all_fees", "authenticity_token"=>"ns37sH/tD/0i5PyMLGfG6bzEb2SHgjwJQGMuV3i3cNE=", "transaction_date"=>"2015-08-03"}
Username : admin Role : Admin
Rendering template within layouts/application
Rendering parent_wise_fee_payments/pay_all_fees

ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass) on line #31 of vendor/plugins/acme_parent_wise_fee_payment/app/views/parent_wise_fee_payments/pay_all_fees.html.erb:
28:       <div class="val themed_text">
29:         <span>:</span>
30:           <div class="val-align">
31:             <%= @guardian.full_name %>
32:           </div>
33:       </div>
34:
```

So the id is null after redirect. You can notice from the production log that the id is missing after action "pay_all_fees". Could you please help me fix this? Is there a way to force passing the id with the authenticity token for example?

UPDATE:

Before getting to this page, the user searches for a guardian, so I'm passing the id from the search page to the current page. Now I need this same id after redirect, I just don't know how.

Comment: You have this `id = params[:id] if params[:id].present?` but I assume it's not losing the param because after that you just check if it's a post request.  If `params[:id]` isn't sent on the post request then you never set id, which means when you redirect it would be nil.  So you need to do something else if it's a post request and params[:id] isn't there

Comment: Try `raise id.inspect` just before the redirect - I'm gonna bet it is nil. Apart of that, you should never have a single action to handle two different type of requests, this is something your routing should handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 if request.post?
        student_id=params[:multi_fees_transaction]["student_id"]
..........
      redirect_to :controller => 'parent_wise_fee_payments', :action => 'pay_all_fees', :student_id=>student_id
```

This way you can use student_id to get the id or something.

Comment: Thank you, this way I can use student_id to calculate id.

Answer (score 0):

The id Variable in

```
redirect_to :controller => 'parent_wise_fee_payments', :action => 'pay_all_fees', :id=>id
```

id not accessible when request is post. Assign the id variable inside the if request.post? block

```
if request.post?
if params[:id].present?
  id = params[:id]
end
the rest of your code
end
```

Comment: id is accessible. Otherwise it would raise 'undefined local variable or method`

Comment: Can you tell me where the id is defined inside the if request.post? block?

Comment: It doesn't need to be defined in this block, code outside of this block is also executed, including the bit you told him to move.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I meant to say that the id isn't passed by the params, if you check the production log, you notice that the id is missing. I need to know how can I pass this id with the post params.